# How to setup default toolbars and menu item?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I need to customize the UI for a group of users at another office.  I want to turn off a bunch of toolbars and menus that are not needed.  I know how to save my configurations (Settings -> Customization...) to a INI file.

How do I setup the other users computers to load the INI at startup?

I am using Windows 7 and Qgis 2.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can start QGIS with the -z option like
`qgis-bin.exe -z e:\test.ini` or if you use OSGEO4W edit the qgis.bat file last line like

```
start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qgis-bin.exe -z e:\test.ini%*
```

Where e:\test.ini is your customized ini file.

Comment: On Windows at least, it's worth adding that the file path to your ini file can be enclosed in single speech marks, so like 'e:\test.ini' rather than e:\test.ini - which is necessary if there are spaces in the file path. You can also create a copy of the qgis.bat file and edit this rather than the original (note that the file is qgis-ltr.bat if using the LTR qgis version). This means that you can set up a new desktop shortcut which launches QGIS using the new bat file - so that you have a choice of launching QGIS with or without the customisation.