# How to open QGIS using a customisation file?

Tags: qgis

I have a customisation file which can provide a much simplified QGIS interface for beginner users. We have QGIS available on a shared machine. I'd like to provide a shortcut which would open QGIS with the simplified interface already active (and another which opens it without customisation). It seems that on Linux this can be done with command line options. Is there some equivalent SIMPLE arrangement for Windows (I'm not a programmer, and I don't have admin permissions on any machines).

Comment: If you installed QGIS using the [OSGeo4W Network Installer](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html), you could use the **OSGeo4W Shell** command prompt program. Simply entering `qgis` would load up QGIS (without customisation). But I never used customisation files before so can't help you with this part. Hopefully others can advise :)

Comment: Joseph - Thanks. Installation at this stage is on a computer by computer basis as I try to introduce QGIS as a useful tool. In effect I'm a fellow worker encouraging uptake of QGIS for simple map/data viewing by non-GIS colleagues, not a administrator of anything at all. Consequently any solutions need to be simple. I'll be able to have support from our (remote) IT people for something which I can explain clearly to them - but work from the assumption that QGIS is a completely alien thing to them at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an answer. Save a ini file with custom ui setting and add that ini file with the z option to the qgis command when starting QGIS

[How to setup default toolbars and menu item?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84178/how-to-setup-default-toolbars-and-menu-item/159696#159696)

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand the answer you've linked to. QGIS on Windows is started up using a shortcut which does (for Windows) relatively complex things. I'm unaware of how to start up from the Windows Command line.

Comment: If you right click the QGIS icon, you can see the path and file that QGIS gets run from. If it is a batch (bat), edit it and add the z-option to command starting QGIS. You can also try to add the option to the target field of the desktop icon properties.

Comment: I'm understanding you to mean to edit the batch file itself? Am I right? Again - no expert on batch files,  but presumably the following line in the file is the key one: [ start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qgis-bin.exe %* ]. If so you're meaning to add the option here? Before or after the '%*' ?

Comment: start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qgis-bin.exe -z e:\test.ini%*

Comment: Hmmm... I can see that this might work, but at the moment it's failing. I can't save a new .bat file into my (or anyone else's) Program Files folder (see comment on other answer about why this is). I can set up a shortcut to a new .bat file (stored in the user's folder), but then it complains about not finding qgis-bin.exe (Thanks for your help on this - I'll write it up into a proper answer if it works). (As you'll gather I'm struggling to understand the operation of the .bat file)

Comment: Please note that it is not helpful for the discoverability of good answers to duplicate questions. Please post your answer to the related question if you work it out. Thank you.

Comment: Made this work at long last and have added a comment on the other question's answer. Still can only make this work if the bat file is in the exact same place as the original qgis.bat / qgis-ltr.bat (C:/OSGEO4SW64/bin)- and can only now do this because we're now using the OSGEO4W installer - meaning that as a non-admin user I can save files here.